# Removed all certs/keys and now can't get push notifications to app deployed to app store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications

I recently deployed my app to the app store where it was approved and push notifications were working just fine. Earlier this week I had to go through and completely delete all keys and certificates from my Keychain Access (Well, maybe I didn't have to in retrospect but I did do the deed because I've gone a bit insane in trying to wrap my head around the entire provisioning/APNS process).

After reading many blogs and tutorials I was assured that you could recreate all of the needed certificates and corresponding keys via your developer provisioning portal. I was indeed **able to do this for my development version** where push notifications are functioning correctly but have **tried to no avail to recreate a valid .pem to plug into my production server** to get a push notification to the app installed from the app store. Below is a detailed list of the steps I took to get to where I am right now:

1. Deleted all keys and certificates from Keychain Access
2. Revoked all certificates(dev and dist) from the provisioning portal
3. Generated new certificates and installed
4. Downloaded ssl aps_developer_identity.cer from portal
5. Downloaded the .p12 key under 'keychain access'->'certificates'->right click and export as DevPushKey.p12
6. openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform der -out DevPushCert.pem
7. openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out DevPushKey.pem -in DevPushKey.p12
8. cat DevPushCert.pem DevPushKey.pem > dev_ck.pem
9. openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert DevPushCert.pem -key DevPushKey.pem

This process works for development but fails for distribution. Any advice or guesses would be greatly appreciated. I'd be glad to provide any further detail that may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

for distribution you need

```
gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

instead of

```
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```